# After open new tab for facebook login does not display any thing

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook login for my one web project i created my app with following settings:

```
app domain - dev.aval-api.appspot.com
Site URL - http://dev.aval-api.appspot.com/
Client OAuth Login - yes
Valid OAuth redirect URIs -http://dev.aval-api.appspot.com/
```

After login with facebook clicked it opened browser new window and there no content or error displayed in that window. url of that browsers new tab is as follow:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=<app_id>&client_id=<app_id>&display=popup&domain=dev.aval-api.appspot.com&e2e=%7B%7D&locale=en_US&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FFX-Xf5fQjUk.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Dfd02cbb44%26domain%3Ddev.aval-api.appspot.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fdev.aval-api.appspot.com%252Ff13c5337a8%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df11297078&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&scope=basic_info%2Cemail%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_likes%2Cuser_relationships%2Cuser_photos%2Cpublish_stream&sdk=joey
```

Comment: You did replace `<app_id>` with your actual app id, right …?

Comment: @CBroe yes i replace it.